# bash script for constructing RNA pipeline

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

I have written a bash script that consists of multiple commands and Python scripts. The goal is to make a pipeline for detecting long non coding RNA from a certain input. Ultimately I would like to turn this into a app and host it on some bioinformatics website. One problem I am facing is using `getopt` tools in bash. I couldn't find a good tutorial that I understand clearly. In addition any other comments related to improving on the code is much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "-h" ]
then
    echo "Usage: sh $0 cuffcompare_output reference_genome blast_file"
    exit
else
wget https://github.com/TransDecoder/TransDecoder/archive/2.0.1.tar.gz && tar xvf 2.0.1 && rm -r 2.0.1
makeblastdb -in $3 -dbtype nucl -out $3.blast.out
grep '"u"' $1 | \
gffread -w transcripts_u.fa -g $2 - && \
python2.7 get_gene_length_filter.py transcripts_u.fa transcripts_u_filter.fa && \
TransDecoder-2.0.1/TransDecoder.LongOrfs -t transcripts_u_filter.fa
sed 's/ .*//' transcripts_u_filter.fa | grep ">" | sed 's/>//' > transcripts_u_filter.fa.genes
cd transcripts_u_filter.fa.transdecoder_dir
sed 's/|.*//' longest_orfs.cds | grep ">" | sed 's/>//' | uniq > longest_orfs.cds.genes
grep -v -f longest_orfs.cds.genes ../transcripts_u_filter.fa.genes > longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes
sed 's/^/>/' longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes > temp && mv temp longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes
python ../extract_sequences.py longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes ../transcripts_u_filter.fa longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa
blastn -query longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa -db ../$3.blast.out -out longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out -outfmt 6
python ../filter_sequences.py longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out.filtered
grep -v -f longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out.filtered longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa > lincRNA_final.fa
fi
```

Here is how I run it:

```
sh test.sh cuffcompare_out_annot_no_annot.combined.gtf /mydata/db/Brapa_sequence_v1.2.fa TE_RNA_transcripts.fa
```

Comment: By `tar xvf 2.0.1 && rm -r 2.0.1` do you mean `tar xvf 2.0.1.tar.gz && rm -r 2.0.1.tar.gz`?

Comment: For some reason when i `wget` the software it is downloaded as `2.0.1` and not as `2.0.1.tar.gz`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script looks like a wall of text and barely readable.
Let's break it down from top to bottom.

#### Simplify the handling of `-h`

Since the `if` at the beginning to check if the first parameter is `-h` will exit if true,
it would be simpler to drop the `else` part entirely:

```
if [ "$1" == -h ]
then
    echo "Usage: sh $0 cuffcompare_output reference_genome blast_file"
    exit
fi
```

I also dropped the quotes around the `-h`, they are not necessary.

#### Validate the command line arguments

The script expects 3 parameters, but doesn't validate if it really received them.
I suggest to rewrite the top part like this:

```
help() {
    exitcode=$1
    echo "Usage: sh $0 cuffcompare_output reference_genome blast_file"
    exit $exitcode
}

[ "$1" == -h ] && help 0
[ $# -lt 3 ] && help 1
```

I added a help function to avoid duplication, because I wasn't too reuse the same help message when exiting the program in both cases:

1. When the first param is -h, print help and exit with 0, meaning success
2. When there are less than 3 params, print help and exit with 1, meaning failure

Instead of if statements I used && expressions to make it shorter and simpler. The result is equivalent.

#### Give the parameters meaningful names

The parameters `$1`, `$2` and `$3` are scattered here and there in the wall of text,
and they are not exactly easy to remember. 
Give them proper names right after validation:

```
cuffcompare_output=$1
reference_genome=$2
blast_file=$3
```

And use these names throughout the script.

#### Taming the wall of text...

Add some line breaks.
Group together lines that are most tightly related.
For example,
for the lines that are the continuation of a pipeline, put
a line break before and after would make this easier to read.
And when a pipeline gets too long,
add some more line breaks (escaped with `\`) to make the important ending part more visible,
for example when redirecting output to a file.

For example, I think this is more readable:

```
wget https://github.com/TransDecoder/TransDecoder/archive/2.0.1.tar.gz && tar xvf 2.0.1 && rm -r 2.0.1

makeblastdb -in $3 -dbtype nucl -out $3.blast.out

grep '"u"' $1 | \
gffread -w transcripts_u.fa -g $2 - && \
python2.7 get_gene_length_filter.py transcripts_u.fa transcripts_u_filter.fa && \
TransDecoder-2.0.1/TransDecoder.LongOrfs -t transcripts_u_filter.fa

sed 's/ .*//' transcripts_u_filter.fa | grep ">" | sed 's/>//' \
> transcripts_u_filter.fa.genes

cd transcripts_u_filter.fa.transdecoder_dir

sed 's/|.*//' longest_orfs.cds | grep ">" | sed 's/>//' | uniq \
> longest_orfs.cds.genes

grep -v -f longest_orfs.cds.genes ../transcripts_u_filter.fa.genes \
> longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes

sed 's/^/>/' longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes \
> temp && mv temp longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes

python ../extract_sequences.py longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes ../transcripts_u_filter.fa longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa

blastn -query longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa -db ../$3.blast.out -out longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out -outfmt 6

python ../filter_sequences.py longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out.filtered

grep -v -f longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out.filtered longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa > lincRNA_final.fa
```

As a small tip, a shorter equivalent of `grep ">" | sed 's/>//'` is `sed -ne 's/>//p'`.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much sense in putting the bulk of your script inside the `else` clause.  Just put the `fi` after exiting prematurely.

```
if [ "$1" == "-h" ]; then
    echo "Usage: sh $0 cuffcompare_output reference_genome blast_file"
    exit
fi
```

You use **temporary files** a lot.  Avoid them whenever possible.  For example:

```
wget -O- https://github.com/TransDecoder/TransDecoder/archive/2.0.1.tar.gz | tar xzvf -
```

That also eliminates the problem of guessing what filename `wget` will decide to give to the downloaded file.

You have very long commands.  It makes sense to put **each pipeline in its own stanza** for readability.

**Develop a habit to double-quote every shell variable** unless you have a reason to use single quotes or no quoting.  Otherwise, Very Bad Things can happen if filenames with special characters are involved.

```
makeblastdb -in "$3" -dbtype nucl -out "$3.blast.out"

grep '"u"' "$1" | \
    gffread -w transcripts_u.fa -g "$2" - && \
    python2.7 get_gene_length_filter.py transcripts_u.fa transcripts_u_filter.fa && \
    TransDecoder-2.0.1/TransDecoder.LongOrfs -t transcripts_u_filter.fa

sed 's/ .*//' transcripts_u_filter.fa | grep ">" | sed 's/>//' > transcripts_u_filter.fa.genes
```

There's a `cd` command buried in there!  Those are tricky since they alter the context of every command that follows.  If you need to do a `cd` at all (and I'd avoid it if possible), I suggest putting the **`cd` in its own subshell,** so that its effect is scoped to the subshell.  (It's less important here, since you only do one `cd`, but such side-effects lead to chaos in larger scripts.)

```
(
    cd transcripts_u_filter.fa.transdecoder_dir

    sed 's/|.*//' longest_orfs.cds | grep ">" | sed 's/>//' | uniq > longest_orfs.cds.genes

    # The rest of the commands here…
)
```

This should be a `grep | sed > longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes` pipeline:

> ```
> grep -v -f longest_orfs.cds.genes ../transcripts_u_filter.fa.genes > longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes
>
> sed 's/^/>/' longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes > temp && mv temp longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes
> ```